# Unknown tomcat account

Tags: tomcat

Recently I have installed Tomcat and today I discovered that tomcat created new user called tomcat. I can't log in into that account with my root password. What does this new user account mean and how can I delete it? I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

[image: New tomcat account]

Second user is my name, and the third one is the new user.

Comment: How did you install tomcat? where you following a tutorial to do so? if so please link it.

Comment: Actually I am using integrated version of IntelliJ IDEA. After the first time, the account was created.